# determine the cutoff frequency of an nMOS in common gate with gate resistance

Tags: mosfet, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency, common-gate

[image]

I have to determine the upper cutoff frequency of this circuit.
I absolutely mustn't use the Laplace domain because it's too time consuming so not compatible with the time I have at the exam.
A rapid calculation shows the capacitances are by no means time separated.
They are not mesh separated.
They are not feedback capacitors so Miller is out of the questions.
I've run out of ideas.

Comment: *I absolutely mustn't use the laplace domain because it's too time consuming* Hmm, then I think you're doing it wrong. How I solve this: draw small signal equivalent circuit, from that determine/estimate poles, zeros and gain and upper cutoff. If Miller comes into play we can only determine from the small signal equivalent circuit (and since the gate is not grounded I expect Cgd to be a miller cap). Your dismiss methods to analyze this circuit for the wrong reasons and that means you cannot find the solution.

Comment: I don't see it being a miller capacitore since it's not a feedback capacitor.in shunt/shunt configuration. I know how to apply miller in this case. Laplace is out of the question because either the solution is straightforward or I don't have time to solve it at the exam

Comment: Then you don't but I do, there's a signal on the gate and there will be a signal of opposite phase on the drain. In the end Miller or not makes no difference as long as you extract the proper network equations.

Comment: so are you saying I should determine the value of the signal on the gate and then treat the transistor as a common source instead of a common gate?

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying **at all**. You should draw the small signal equivalent and take things from there. You should forget about Laplace or no Laplace and Miller or no Miller, you should focus on the small signal equivalent circuit. You're thinking in: if then that, if that then this. That's a dangerous approach, instead focus on methods which can be universally applied like the small signal approach and network equations.

Comment: I drew the small signal and determined the gain and I don't see HOW i can apply the universal method you are talking about.

Comment: You just used it to determine the gain, you used network equations to find the gain. Ohm's Law, KVL, KCL etc. Since you managed to solve the gain then I think you're overthinking the whole exercise. Now fill in Zc = 1/ 2pifC = 1/sC for the capacitors and evaluate again.